# Error compiling std::count() in solaris

Tags: c++, stl, stl-algorithm

I am using std::count() in my code. My code is successfully build in windows but I am unable to compile this under Solaris,

Complete function is given below,

```
unsigned int 
BBGENTVerify::tokenizeTickerEID(const std::string p_czTickerEIDs,\
                                std::vector<int>& p_rTickerEIDsVector){

    int l_iStartPos = -1;
    int l_iEndPos   = -1;

    unsigned int l_iEIDsPresent = std::count(p_czTickerEIDs.c_str(), \
                        p_czTickerEIDs.c_str() + p_czTickerEIDs.size(), ',') + 1;
    do{
        l_iEndPos = p_czTickerEIDs.find(",", l_iStartPos + 1);
        if (l_iEndPos == -1){
            l_iEndPos = p_czTickerEIDs.size() - l_iStartPos;
        }
        p_rTickerEIDsVector.push_back(atoi\
            (p_czTickerEIDs.substr(l_iStartPos +1, l_iEndPos).c_str()));
        l_iStartPos = l_iEndPos;
    }while(p_rTickerEIDsVector.size() < l_iEIDsPresent);

    return p_rTickerEIDsVector.size();
}
```

I am getting error,

```
"src/fileENTForP.cpp", line 136: Error: Could not find a match for std::count<std::InputIterator, std::T, std::Size>(const char*, const char*, char) needed in BBGENTVerify::tokenizeTickerEID(const std::string, std::vector<int>&).
1 Error(s) detected.
clearmake: Error: Build script failed for "release/sun_solaris64/BBGENTVerify.o"\
```

**This code is successfully compiled in windows platform.**
I did some investigation and found that Solaris complier is somehow taking some other template signature, with one extra parameter.

```
Error: Could not find a match for std::count<std::InputIterator, std::T, std::Size>
(const char*, const char*, char)
```

whereas standard says the signature,

```
template <class InputIterator, class T>
  typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type
    count (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val);
```

Code is expecting this signature

```
std::count<std::InputIterator, std::T, std::Size>
```

where as I am using/also what standard C++ supports,

```
template <class InputIterator, class T>
std::count(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val);
```

Please help me with this code.

Comment: Mostly you talk about std::count but you also mention std::copy() - typo?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using a version of the RogueWave standard C++ library (this library is still the default although the STLport version is the recommended one). This implementation demands an initial value for the count:

```
int c = std::count(begin, end, match, init);
```

The background is that the idea of `std::iterator_traits` wasn't around when this implementation first shipped!

When I encountered this problem I have created an auxiliary header which just forwarded the algorithm call in a consistent way:

```
#ifndef INCLUDED_STLAUX
#define INCLUDED_STLAUX

#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

namespace aux {
template <typename It, type name Value>
typenane std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type
count (It begin, It end, Value value) {
#ifdef _SUNC_PRO
    typename std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type rc(0);
    std::count(begin, end, value, rc);
    return rc;
#else
    return std::count(begin, end, value);
#endif
}

#endif
```

(the code is typed on a mobile device and probably contains some errors; I'm especially not sure about the proper macro to test).

In the actual code I would the consistently use `aux::count()`.

Comment: Thanks @Dietmar this solution seems really promising... But I am just wondering that why Solaris is still supporting this..And this thought puts me into another thought that there could be another way!

Comment: @BhupeshPant: Sun is very strongly set not to break their interfaces and they keep the entire RogueWave implementation unchanged due to this.